# RegionPlot on integer domain

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create a RegionPlot on (x,y) to compare two functions f(x,y) and g(x,y).
The usual command:

```
RegionPlot[f[x, y] < g[x, y], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

seems to be taking forever to run for some reason. Possibly because one of the two functions is coming from the output of an `NMaximise[]`.

I am not looking for a complete plot, but rather a rough idea of which function is greater where. So I am looking to do so only for the integer coordinates, which I expect to be much quicker. What would be the way to code this up, or is there a short-cut approach/option for it?

Comment: Please provide enough code that readers can run your computation and observe the problem that you are encountering.  Otherwise, there is little readers can do to help you.

Comment: You could make a table:  `dat=Table[ Boole[wf[x, y] < g[x, y]], {x, 0, 100,10}, {y, 0, 100,10}];` and then plot the data with `ListPlot3D[dat` ]

Comment: `RegionPlot` may not work for some cases,we can use `ContourPlot` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of generating points on a grid, and then selecting only those for which $f(x,y)<g(x,y)$. Both plots are compared, you should, obviously, generate only `lPlot`.

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 x + y;
g[x_, y_] := 5 y + 2 Sin[x];

rPlot = RegionPlot[f[x, y] < g[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}];

points = Select[Catenate@Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}], (f @@ #) < (g @@ #) &];
lPlot = ListPlot[points];

Show[rPlot, lPlot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `DiscretePlot3D[Boole[2 x + y < 5 y + Sin[x]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]`  also deserves attention to this end.